# How to draw random number from array in basic4android?

Tags: arrays, basic4android

I am very new to Basic4Android programming. I just want to know how to draw a random number from an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by randomizing the total number of items in array example if the items are 10, then randomize first and pass it to a variable. later use that variable to call the array value. Copy the code below and paste in Activity Create Sub and Run

```
Dim myArray As List  ' Declare your Array
myArray.Initialize() ' Initialize array

myArray.AddAll(Array As String("January","February","March","April"))

'Since array values index starts from zero, then four items in a list will be from 0 to 3. 
'So randomize 0 to 4    
Dim randNum As Int

randNum = Rnd(1,4)  'Generating random number 

Log ("Current RAndom Number is " & randNum) 'This will print the random number

    '=========PRINT RESULT TO LOGCAT ======
'Since we are generating from 1 to 4, we use -1 (4-1=3 ie April ==Array index starts from 0 to 3)
Log(myArray.Get(randNum-1))
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot! :)

Comment: Am glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim arrayLength as int = 100     ' an arbitrary integer >0 
Dim myArray(arrayLength) as int  ' or double, float, long, byte...

' ... fill the array ...

Log(myArray(Rnd(0,arrayLength)))  ' "Rnd" goes from 0 (incl) to arrayLength (excl)
```